# open account new detail page on click of a button

Tags: page-layout

Is it possible to open a account's new button detail page from a detail button on another object?

I know we can open a custom apex page through a detail button by putting in the url but can we open a standard page

Comment: Do you wan to open a new Account creation page from the detail view of a record?

Comment: Yes Manjit.Thats exactly i want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to open the account details page from a button. You may create a Detail page button and choose `Behavior` as `URL` and use the following code `{!URLFOR( $Action.Account.New )}`.

This will ask you to select a record type if you want to set the default record type of the user, you may use `Execute Javascript` in `Behaviour` and use the following code:

```
window.open('/001/e');
```

Please see this [document](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=defining_custom_links.htm&language=en_US) for additional details.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a small visualforce page which will be embedded at top of account detail page who's function is to redirect to a visualforce page which created new record by apex controller.